# I am trying to generate Speech with audition but option is not visible

Tags: audition

I am trying to generate Speech with audition but option is not visible on mac pro system please see image for reference [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmUGD.png)

Version: audition cc 2014

for system speech ref:
[image: click here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate Speech was added in [Audition CC 2015.1](https://www.provideocoalition.com/what-s-new-in-audition-cc-2015-1/). You will need to update to use that feature.

Comment: and what about  Audition  CS6 ?  for me its not available in cs6 also

Comment: CS6 is older. You need to be using Audition CC at the 2015.1 release or newer to use the Generate Speech feature.